# how to make this redundant javascript more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using jQuery to ajaxify validations for a Rails form. The script below works nicely, but I know there is a way to make it more efficient by declaring the field name and the error message string and then making the script run through the list, but I'm not yet sophisticated enough to write that.

What is the right way to rewrite it?

```
$( '.sendername' ).blur(function() {
  if ($('.sendername').val() == "") {
      $('.sendername-err').text('This field is required.');
      $('.sendername').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $('.sendername-err').text('');
    $('.sendername').removeClass('invalid');
  }
});

$( '.email' ).blur(function() {
  if ($('.email').val() == "") {
      $('.email-err').text('You've forgotten this.');
      $('.email').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $('.email-err').text('');
    $('.email').removeClass('invalid');
  }
});

$( '.subject' ).blur(function() {
  if ($('.subject').val() == "") {
      $('.subject-err').text('Please enter a value.');
      $('.subject').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $('.subject-err').text('');
    $('.subject').removeClass('invalid');
  }
});

$( '.message' ).blur(function() {
  if ($('.message').val() == "") {
      $('.message-err').text('Zero characters is too short.');
      $('.message').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $('.message-err').text('');
    $('.message').removeClass('invalid');
  }
});
```

I'm asking because I'd like to understand how to write better javascript going forward. Similar situations come up often and it makes me bananas to do it this way.

Comment: If you want a code review, ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: I didn't know about this. I think I will become a regular. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup doesn't look consistent enough, but you could create a more consistent naming standard (make all the suffixes and prefixes the same - for example, always use -name or never use it), then use a function:

```
function setup_field(name, message) { 
  $( '.'+name+'-name' ).blur(function() {
    if ($('.'+name+'-name').val() == "") {
        $('.'+name+'-err').text(message);
        $('.'+name+'-name').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $('.'+name+'-err').text('');
      $('.'+name+'-name').removeClass('invalid');
    }
  });
}
```

Then you just call that for each field:

```
setup_field('sender', 'This field is required.');
setup_field('email', "You've forgotten this.");
setup_field('subject', 'Please enter a value.');
setup_field('message', 'Zero characters is too short.');
```

The point of course is to use a function. You can even make it flexible enough to allow you to define each of the classes as differently as you like by just adding more variables to the function signature; `setup_field(field_class, err_class, message)`, then plugging those variables into the above function where appropriate. But that would make your setup area more verbose.

Comment: This is --exactly-- what I had in mind. Also, you are right, I had a typo, which I've fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would loop through all of those root names, and put all of the code in there.

Also, don't forget to escape the apostrophe in `you've`

And, as Pointy pointed out, inside of your jQuery event handler, the `this` value will be set to the element in question.  If the `-err` element is always right next to the element in question, you could further simplify by replacing

```
$(name + '-err').text('You\'ve forgotten this.');
```

with

```
$el.next().text('You\'ve forgotten this.');
```

---

```
['.email', '.subject', '.message'].forEach(function(name){
    $(name).blur(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      if ($el.val() == "") {
          $(name + '-err').text('You\'ve forgotten this.');
          $el.addClass('invalid');
      } else {
          $(name + '-err').text('');
          $el.removeClass('invalid');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Surely you'd want to take advantage of the fact that jQuery ensures that the actual element involved in the event is available via `this`.

Comment: I didn't understand as well as with the one above how to plug in the different error messages, but this helped me get the gist of how to make a bunch of functions into one generally. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
var dataObj = {
        "sender": "This field is required.",
        "email": "You've forgotten this.",
        "subject": "Please enter a value.",
        "message": "Zero characters is too short."
    },
    N = "-name",
    E = "-err",
    D = ".",
    I = "invalid",
    fn = function(el) {
        $( D + el + N ).blur(function() {
            var $el = $(D + el + N);
            if ($el.val() === "") {
                $(D + el + E).text(dataObj[el]);
                $el.addClass(I);
            } else {
                $(D + el + N + E).text('');
                $el.removeClass(I);
            }
        });
    };

for(var el in dataObj) {
    fn(el);
}
```

Comment: This was hard to understand at first but now I see what is happening. I would use it without the NEDI and just put in the values. Thank you - this helped in understanding how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
var CSS_CLASS_INVALID = 'invalid';
function newCallbackForFieldAndErrorWithMessage(item) {
    return function () {
        var error_message = item.error_message,
            $field = $(item.field_selector),
            $error = $(item.error_selector),
            text;
        if ($field.val() == "") {
            text = error_message;
            $field.addClass(CSS_CLASS_INVALID);
        } else {
            text = '';
            $field.removeClass(CSS_CLASS_INVALID);
        }
        $error.text(text);
    };
}
var fields = [{
    field_selector: '.sender-name',
    error_selector: '.sender-name-err',
    error_message: 'This field is required.'
}, {
    field_selector: '.email',
    error_selector: '.email-err',
    error_message: 'You\'ve forgotten this.'
}, {
    field_selector: '.subject',
    error_selector: '.subject-err',
    error_message: 'Please enter a value.'
}, {
    field_selector: '.message',
    error_selector: '.message-err',
    error_message: 'Zero characters is too short.'
}];

$.each(fields, function (index, item) {
    $(item.field_selector).blur(newCallbackForFieldAndErrorWithMessage(item));
});
```

You can test the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dragulceo/8dPPE/

Answer (score 0):

Okay replace all the $( '.sender-name' ) with variabels.

var Names = $( '.sender-name' );
then use the variable instead. Looking up the elements in the dom tree takes some time for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more fluent validation technique (declarative vs. procedural).  Please see my answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37852/making-the-code-smaller-and-manageable/37853#37853).

Comment: I'm using the native Rails validation on "Submit", and I also wanted ajax validation on blur for required fields. Your solution is a good one that I may be able to modify - I'm copying it, but in this case I  wanted to learn how to condense a bunch of similar functions into one.

Comment: When you use the declarative approach, you have a single unchanging code base and a number of attributes you put on the controls to be validated.  The amount of code doesn't increase when you add more controls.  So this does in fact condense a bunch of similar functions into one.